# What happens when assign a return value from a method to a Class type variable in Java?

Tags: java, object, methods, reference, parameter-passing

I have a public class Dog.

Method 1:

```
public Dog getDog(Dog dog){
    if(dog.size>0){
      return dog;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Method 2:

```
public Dog getNewDog(){
   return new Dog();
}
```

Finally, assigning the method return value back:-

```
Dog mydog = new Dog();
Dog d2 = new Dog();

Dog c = mydog.getDog(d2);   // are we assigning a reference variable back to another reference?
Dog k = mydog.getNewDog(); // Are we assigning a new dog object itself to the Dog type variable.
```

now, why do we always assign back value from a method to a Reference variable? I have seen this everywhere in Java.

Comment: Please try to improve the question

Comment: @Aman , should i be more specific?

Comment: When you ask why “we” do “always” do X, don’t forget to include what you think we could do instead of X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer the questions you have put as comments:
A. Why do we always assign back value from a method to a Reference variable? - Not necessarily true.
There are some classes once given a value, you can't change it. This are called `Immutable`. For instance, `String` is immutable, so once you assign it a value you can't change that same string. Let's see the following
example:

```
String s1 = "1";
String s2 = s1.concat("2")
s2.concat("3");
System.out.println(s2); // print out 12
```

The output is **12**. The reason is that, whenever you call a method that changes the value you have to assign it back or you will lose the new value.
For an `Immutable` object, as you can see, it is necessary that you reassign. But, this are special classes. In the case of `Dog`, you don't have to assign it every time change its properties. Unless you explicitly needed to create a new `Dog` Object.

B. Are we assigning a new dog object itself to the Dog type variable?
Whenever you declare a variable of type reference(that extends Object), it will be assigned null. And if you try to access its properties, it results in `NullPointerException`. So, keep in mind that you have to assign a value to it.

Note that `Dog k = mydog.getNewDog();` is equivalent to saying `Dog k = new Dog();` in your code.

C. Are we assigning a reference variable back to another reference?
Let's see your code:

```
public Dog getDog(Dog dog){
    if(dog.size>0){
        return dog;
    }
    return null;
}
        
Dog d2 = new Dog();
Dog c = mydog.getDog(d2);
```

For this piece of code:

- if `dog.size > 0` is true, `d2` and `c` will be referencing to the same object. So, any change you make to one of them will reflect on both.
- if `dog.size > 0` is false, `c` will be assigned `null`

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing is assignig new Dog objects to variable c and k, which results in overwriting the previously saved dogs.

It does not have to be done like this, but it can be useful in at least three cases:

- sometimes this way results in less lines of code
- if you used your previously linked object in other places, you might not want to change it everywhere. If a method returns a new (transformed) object, you can make sure the old object can still be used in other places
- this pattern could be used for builders or chaining. if a method returns a dog (no matter if it is a new or an old one) you may directly continue writing more method calls on the same line. Example: mydog.getNewDog().bark();